# Manipulate data for scaling

Tags: python, c++

I have this data:

```
Game 1: 7.0/10.0, Reviewed: 1000 times
Game 2: 7.5/10.0, Reviewed: 3000 times
Game 3: 8.9/10.0, Reviewed: 140,000 times
Game 4: 10.0/10.0 Reviewed: 5 times
.
.
.
```

I want to manipulate this data in a way to make each rating reflective of how many times it has been reviewed.

For example Game 3 should have a little heavier weight than than Game 4, since it has been reviewed way more. 
And Game 2's 7 should be weighted more than Game 1's 7.

Is there a proper function to do this scaling? In such a way that

ScaledGameRating = OldGameRating * (some exponential function?)

Comment: Somewhat off-topic, but this question is perhaps better suited for the Mathematics StackExchange site. http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply normalizing the average scores (i.e. subtract 5, the midpoint of the scoring interval) and multiply by the number of reviews? That will weight positive or negative scores according to the number of reviews.

Using this approach, you get the following values for your four games:

```
Game 1:     2,000  (7-5)*1000
Game 2:     7,500  (7.5-5)*3000
Game 3:   546,000  (8.9-5)*140000
Game 4:        25  (10-5)*5
```

Normalizing works well with negatively reviewed games because a game with a large number of negative (<5) reviews will not beat a game with a small number of positive (>5) reviews. That won't be the case if you use the absolute scores without normalizing.

Comment: I like this idea, but is there a way to bring this down a more controlled range of scores? For example I am getting scored from -4000 to 400k+

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "controlled". If you are referring to the huge result for game 3, that's a reflection of the fact that it's been reviewed extremely frequently (50x more than the next most reviewed game and has a very high average score). Of course, you could scale the result by any factor you like (e.g. multiply by .01) but that will skew your results -- it's really a question of how much you want to weigh frequency vs. average score. My proposal puts a high weight on frequency but I'd suggest playing with some alternatives and see what works best for you.

Comment: By controlled meaning is there anyway I can feed the new scores into a function and get back a compressed score from 1 to 10 while still maintaining the difference

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

Find 
Total Reviews

for Rating out of 10 you can just get
**Game x Rating : ( (Number of times Game x Reviewed) / (Total Reviews) ) * 10**

will give you out of 10 rating.That is weight of the particular game reviewed in total games present.

Comment: It'll make commonly reviewed rubbish game (rating 0.1) better than some fresh good game.

Answer (score 0):

My Take in this problem is different. Considering if the review count is less, the remaining review are unknown and could have been anywhere between 1 through 10. So we can do a random distribution over the missing range and find the average over the entire maximum review population

```
max_freq = max(rating, key = itemgetter(1))[-1]
>>> for r,f in rating:
    missing = max_freq - f
    actual_rating = r
    if missing:
        actual_rating = sum(randint(1,10) for e in range(missing))/ (10.0*missing)
    print "Original Rating {}, Scaled Rating {}".format(r, actual_rating)


Original Rating 0.7, Scaled Rating 0.550225179856
Original Rating 0.75, Scaled Rating 0.550952554745
Original Rating 0.89, Scaled Rating 0.89
Original Rating 1, Scaled Rating 0.54975249116)


Original Rating 0.7, Scaled Rating 0.550576978417
Original Rating 0.75, Scaled Rating 0.549582481752
Original Rating 0.89, Scaled Rating 0.89
Original Rating 1, Scaled Rating 0.550458230651
```